# I cannot convert this datetime string from Django to iOS NSDate

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting NSString `2012-08-17T10:56:45.508205` as time from Django API.

I am trying to convert that string into `NSDate` object with this code:

```c
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToConvert];
```

But date object is null. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) string you're getting from the Django API (2012-08-17T10:56:45.508205) does not include a time zone component.  However, you are including that field symbol (Z) in your format string.  Just remove that and it should work fine.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

See the [Unicode Technical Reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information on the formatting codes: